# JSF2 Spring JDK Proxied Session Bean Overhead Question

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, proxy, jsf-2

In my current app (JSF2, Spring 3, Richfaces 4, WebFlow 2.x) have a string which I need session scoped(so each user has their own copy).

My question is how much overhead is involved in creating and maintaining a spring/JSF2 bean in a spring managed container?  Should I make a bean just for this string? or should I include this string in an already existing bean? (the user bean in my case).  Right now I have the string contained in its own wrapped bean class.  My initial thought was that if I included it the string in the User bean, then I would be including a bunch of extra stuff(everything else in the user bean) each time something needs the aforementioned string. eg. it seems to make more sense to just wire up a bean containing just the needed string as apposed to wiring a bean that contains a bunch of extra stuff that never gets used.  Anyone have any experience/thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is an article](http://blog.springsource.com/2007/07/19/debunking-myths-proxies-impact-performance/) on the spring blog which discusses the impact of proxies on performance.

I don't fully understand your situation, but I don't think it's worth creating a bean for each string. Not because of performance, but because of readability and maintainability. (Also check the spring annotation `@Value(..)` for injecting primitives)